# Node.js return res

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I have to modify the code below, so that rates: sayHello() works?
If I call rates: testFunction() it works and console.log(res); in sayHello works as well. Thanks.

```
    exports.getRates = (req, res) => {
      res.render('riscalc/rates', {
        title: 'Riscalc',
        rates: sayHello()

      });
    };

    function testFunction() {
      return 23;
    }


    function sayHello() {
      client.invoke('s_hello', 'hello', (error, res, more) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } else {
                // console.log(res);
          return res;
        }
        if (!more) {
          console.log('Done.');
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve with the code. However, assuming that `client.invoke`'s callback is called only once, then using 'callback' function in `sayHello` function, the following code should work:

```
exports.getRates = (req, res) => {

    sayHello(function (err, val) {
        res.render('riscalc/rates', {
            title: 'Riscalc',
            rates: val
        });
    });

};

function testFunction() {
    return 23;
}


function sayHello(callback) {
    client.invoke('s_hello', 'hello', (error, res, more) => {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            // console.log(res);
            callback(null, res)
        }
        if (!more) {
            console.log('Done.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Great that works. Thanks. I was stuck with the callback function. client.invoke ist a zerorpc call. const zerorpc = require('zerorpc');

const client = new zerorpc.Client();
client.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:4242');

Comment: What was the downvote for?

Comment: Sorry false click.

Comment: Hope you correct that :-)

Comment: I can't, when clicking up arrow nothing happens.